# Why django admin page refuse to connect?

Tags: django, django-admin

Whenever I run the command python manage.py runserver, the server gets starts without any error , but whenever i try to visit the admin page http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ , it keeps showing the error that:

127.0.0.1 refused to connect

Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtNHT.png)

Comment: Is the browser on the same machine where you are running `python manage.py runserver`? For example, if you are using a virtual machine or a docker container, then 127.0.0.1 might not be correct. What is the output when you run `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: did you migrate properly and did you try http://localhost:8000/admin.

Comment: yes, I did the migration part  and the server is running on the same browser  but whenever i am trying to reach to the admin the server breaks.

Comment: I tried it with localhost:8000/admin but still the server breaks and shows error on the browser that "local host refused to connect" @ngawang13

Comment: Is your project running in docker or a VM? Can you acces 127.0.0.1:8000 without admin?